# '_Screen' object has no attribute 'tk' when trying to use canvasvg.saveall() on turtle

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter, save, python-turtle

I have made a strange program that can draw fractals and circles and spirals and I have been trying for hours to get a way to save the turtle output to a image file (preferably png or jpeg).
I am getting the '_Screen' object has no attribute 'tk' when trying to use canvasvg.saveall() on turtle. here is the code:

```
import turtle
import random
import canvasvg

root = turtle.Screen()
drawing = 1
def save():
    canvasvg.saveall("spircles.svg", root)
print("turning angle:")
turningangle = float(input())
print("size:")
forward = float(input())
print("spiral:")
try:
    spiral = float(input())
    if spiral == None:
        spiral = random.random()
except:
    pass
    spiral = random.random()
turtle = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed(speed=0)
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.ht()
print("drawing. spiral:", spiral)
try:
    while drawing == 1:
        root.listen()
        root.onkey(save, "s")
        turtle.left(turningangle)
        turtle.forward(forward)
        turningangle += spiral
        spiral += (spiral / turningangle)
except Exception as e:
    drawing = 0
    pass
    print("done. press enter to exit. error:", e)
    input()
    exit()
turtle.mainloop()
```

anybody know an easy way of doing this?  have tried PIL and it hasn't worked. I also want to not have to install third party programs. I want to be able to install some modules with pip (if necessary) and be able to run it without hassle. it should save to an image file when the user presses "s".

I have tried PIL, and canvasvg.saveall() and I want canvasvg.saveall() as it seems to be the easiest way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Turtle uses `tkinter.Canvas` to draw your shapes, the `Screen` object is not a `tkinter.Canvas` object, nor is it a `tkinter.Widget` at all. Turtle provides a method for this task, it's called [`turtle.getcanvas`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.getcanvas) and you can use it on your [`Screen` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.TurtleScreen). So `canvas = root.getcanvas()` should work just fine.

It seems like you can use [`canvasvg.saveall(filename, canvas)`](https://github.com/WojciechMula/canvas2svg#saveallfilename-canvas-itemsnone-margin10-tounicodenone), but be aware that they state [not all items are supported](https://github.com/WojciechMula/canvas2svg#tkinter-canvas-to-svg-exporter).

```
def save():
    canvas = root.getcanvas()
    canvasvg.saveall("spircles.svg", canvas)
```